# Filtering ngTable AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, ngtable

Here's my plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview

My code:

```
<p>
    <input type="radio" id="360" name="Composed-group" value="360" ng-model="$parent.selectedType">
    <label for="360">360</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="radio" id="2D" name="Composed-group" value="2D" ng-model="$parent.selectedType">
    <label for="2D">2D</label>
</p>

<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="name in $data | filter:{type:selectedType}">
        <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">{{name.name}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center" data-title="'Type'" filter="{ type: 'text'}" sortable="'type'">{{name.type}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Date'" sortable="'time'">{{name.time | date:'MMM d, y H:mm:ss'}}</td>                  
    </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is - after filter ex '2D' - in output I've got 3 data's, in 3 pages of table. I want to show all in first page - because 1 page can shows 3 data's.
Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: It is doable, but there is a problem when you have large tables. Say that each of your 3 tables has 100 2D types. When you filter 2D, do you still want them to be in one page/first page?

Comment: I said it is doable because you can just grab whatever you filter from the other two tables and put it into your first table. But it leads to another problem. Say that you have all the filtered items in the first table. When users click on the second/third page, what should they see?

Comment: @CharlieNg I wan't to filtered data shows sortable beginning 1 page - 2page -3page ...

Comment: @CharlieNg I find something like this : http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-custom-template   -  i want to filter like in this ex.